# how to add binary numbers

Tags: java, binary

I have to methods here. One converts decimal number to 8 bit binary. I need to add another method that will add two binary number together. For example 01000000 (64) + 00000010(2) = 01000010(66). Then for the second method for example 34 + 56 equal 90 then the binary equivalent which 01011010. So I would need a method that performs that. So if the user was asked for two decimal numbers it would take the two and add them. Out putting the answer in binary (8 bits)

This converts a decimal to binary, I need to some how get it to add two binary numbers

```
public String toBinary(int number)
{
    String binary = " ";
    boolean isNeg = number < 0;
    if(isNeg)
    {
        number += 1;
    }
    while (number > 0 || number < 0) {
        int rem = number%2; 
        if(rem == -1)
        {
            rem = rem * -1;
        }
        binary = rem + binary;
        number /= 2; 

    } 
    while(binary.length() <= 8)
    {
        binary = "0" + binary;
    }

    if(isNeg)
    {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer("");
        for(int i =0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            char store = binary.charAt(i);  
            if(store == '0')
            {
                buff.append("1");

            }else
            {
                buff.append("0");
            }

        }  

        binary = buff.toString();
    }     

    return binary;
}
```

converts binary to decimal i need to fix it to work for negative binary (singed) then be able to add two binary numbers

```
public int toDecimal(int number)
{
    int decimal = 0;
    int p = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        if(number ==0)
        {
            break;
        }else if(number > 0) {
            int temp = number%10;
            decimal +=temp*Math.pow(2,p);
            number = number/10;
            p++;
        }



    }
    return decimal;
```

}}

Comment: In binary 0 + 0 = 0; 0 + 1 = 1; and 1 + 1 = 0 carry 1;

Comment: Once you have your two binary strings. Use Integer.parse(yourString.Charat(index)); to add idential indexes. Don't forget to handle carrying one when needed. Build a result string from each addition.

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry to tell you that but ... both methods already exists, but great if you tried to code them

```
//The method to convert from int to Binary already exists : Integer.toBinaryString(int i)
System.out.println(toBinary(16)+" <=> "+Integer.toBinaryString(16));
//The method to convert from Binary to int (with String) too : Integer.parseInt(String s,2)
System.out.println(toDecimal(00010000)+" <=> "+Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(10000),2));
```

For the 'add' method just use your 2 other methods :

```
public String addBinary(int a, int b){
        return toBinary(toDecimal(a)+toDecimal(b));
}
```

For you toDecimal : NEVER USE `while(true)` it's very risky, and instantiate your variable outside of the loop (here the else if) because your are creating a new one each time : use memory

Comment: I'm guessing this is a homework assignment, so the OP would not be able to use Integer.toBinaryString and similar.

Comment: The same goes for the `addBinary` method.  You wouldn't be able to use the Java addition operator to add multi-digit numbers, since that would defeat the purpose of the assignment.

Comment: yea i cant use any of those