# How to understand the functioning of the code about binary number?

Tags: java

urcemenu

share

￼

Java Exercises: Add two binary numbers

Last update on July 05 2018 13:07:21 (UTC/GMT +8 hours)

Java Basic: Exercise-17 with Solution

Write a Java program to add two binary numbers.

In digital electronics and mathematics, a binary number is a number expressed in the base-2 numeral system or binary numeral system. This system uses only two symbols: typically 1 (one) and 0 (zero).

Test Data:
Input first binary number: 100010
Input second binary number: 110010

Pictorial Presentation:

￼

Sample Solution:

Java Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise17 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long binary1, binary2;
        int i = 0, remainder = 0;
        int[] sum = new int[20];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input first binary number: ");
        binary1 = in.nextLong();
        System.out.print("Input second binary number: ");
        binary2 = in.nextLong();
        while (binary1 != 0 || binary2 != 0) {
            sum[i++] = (int) ((binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) % 2);
            remainder = (int) ((binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) / 2);
            binary1 = binary1 / 10;
            binary2 = binary2 / 10;
        }
        if (remainder != 0) {
            sum[i++] = remainder;
        }
        --i;
        System.out.print("Sum of two binary numbers: ");
        while (i >= 0) {
            System.out.print(sum[i--]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: please format the code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the program will be running on the console. Therefore, the user can already provide the input on the console:

> Example: > myProgram.java 00110000 00010000
>
> (remember: you have to compile your program with javac first)

You can simply access the given numbers with args[ 0 ] and args[ 1 ]

Your approach - using "long" as the datatype - might not work as well because the Scanner expects a number of type long - String might be an option as input type which will be parsed afterwards.

Here a  [reference (to the code below)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098892/how-to-add-binary-numbers) of the same question which has already been marked as duplicate. By using those given methods you will accomplish your task very quickly.
If you are not allowed to use those, then you will have to think of the binary system and how addition works in the binary system - Ultimately, transform those thoughts into code.:

```
//The method to convert from int to Binary already exists : Integer.toBinaryString(int i)
System.out.println(toBinary(16)+" <=> "+Integer.toBinaryString(16));

//The method to convert from Binary to int (with String) too : Integer.parseInt(String s,2)
System.out.println(toDecimal(00010000)+" <=> "+Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(10000),2));
```

For the 'add' method just use your 2 other methods :

```
public String addBinary(int a, int b){
        return toBinary(toDecimal(a)+toDecimal(b));
}
```

And here the same question which has been referenced by the previously linked question because it has been duplicate: 
[many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548586/adding-binary-numbers)